# Permutation and Combination Problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Hey folks I'm having some issues with permutation and combination problems.

1) Make a 3 digit even number without repeated digits, using  0, 4, 5 , 6, 7. Also the first digit cannot be 0.

I figured it must be 4 X 4 x 3 = 48 because the first digit can be 4 digits. The second digit can also be 4 because you can use 0 but not the digit you already used and the third can be 3 because you can't use 5 or 7.

2)Arrange 12 blocks in a line, 4 of which are green, 3 of which are blue, and 5 red, so that all blocks are adjacent. No clue what this even means...

3)form a 5 digit number using each digit 1 through  5 so that 4 & 5 are not adjacent

4)Form a 5 digit without zeroes, with exactly four distinct digits (that is, one digit should be repeated).

Comment: You are wrong in 1). For the third you cannot pick $5$ and $7$ **and** you cannot pick the digits that are allready in use.

Comment: @drhab so would 4 x 4 x 1 be correct? Thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974432/permutations-and-combinations-3-digit-number

Comment: I am afraid not and worked out my hint as an [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/974532/75923) on [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/974432/75923).

Answer (score 1):

3) There are 5! way to permute the numbers. For each of these 120 permutations, there are 4 pairs of adjacent numbers. There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ types of such pairs. That is for each permutation chances that 4 and 5 are adjacent are 4/10, hence the result becomes $5!*(1-4/10)$.

4) Firstly choose 4 numbers. There are $\binom{9}{4}$ ways.
Now choose one of the 4 numbers to double. There are $\binom{4}{1}$.
Now permute the numbers. There are $\binom{5}{2,1,1,1}=\frac{5!}{2!\cdot1!\cdot1!\cdot1!}$
The result is the product of these 3 numbers.

Comment: how did you figure there are 4 pairs of adjacent numbers per 120 permutations. And also how did you get 5C2? Thanks!

Comment: All numbers in the permutations are different so no matter what there will be 4 (without ordering). E.g. the permutation {3,4,2,1,5} has {3,4} ; {2,4} ; {1,2} ; {1,5}. Now that I choose to do this without ordering, all you need to construct such a pair is to choose 2 number of 5. Hence there are 5C2 types.

Comment: @Coolwater,The question asks for not adjacent.  The way to go about doing it is total number of ways is 5! = 120.  Fix 45 as one and they could be permuted by 2 ways as 45 and 54.  Now you have four numbers to permute = 2*4! = 48. Subtract 48 from 120 and you get 72 that is the answer.

Comment: @Coolwater, for the last question, take any one digit.  You could choose it in 9 ways. The same digit, you have one way to choose.  The remainder of the digits could be chosen in 8*7*6 ways. The special repeater digit could be placed among the five digits in ${5\choose2}=10$ ways.  Thus the total is 9*8*7*6*10 = 30240 ways.  This is another way of doing it.

Comment: @Coolwater, which country are you from.  Using chances to solve Permuation problems, quite new to me.

Comment: @satishramanathan Ye you are right it's 72. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint on 1):

- How many numbers can be made if it is not demanded that the number is even?
- How many of these numbers end up with a $5$? And how many with a $7$?