# Permutations and Combinations? 3 digit number...

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

1) Make a 3 digit even number without repeated digits, using 0, 4, 5 , 6, 7. Also the first digit cannot be 0.

2)Arrange 12 books in a line, 4 of which are english, 3 of which are science, and 5 calculus, so that all books of same subject are adjacent.

Comment: What has been your approach so far? It's not fair to straight away ask for solutions.

Comment: @bhavesh for 1) I figured it must be 4 X 4 x 3 = 48 because the first digit can be 4 digits. The second digit can also be 4 because you can use 0 but not the digit you already used and the third can be 3 because you can't use 5 or 7.

Comment: @bhavesh and for 2) i have no idea how to start

Comment: for the first one is repetition allowed ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your first question:
case01:Repetition is not allowed
You can see that in a three digit number there are three place ie. One ten and hundred
Now hundred's place can have 4 numbers 4,5,6 or 7.so 4 ways
Now ten place again 4 numbers can be accommodate 0 , and from other 3 remaining because repetition is not allowed. so 4 ways 
Now ones place 3 numbers can be accommodate so 3 ways 
Now total ways would be 4x4x3=48 numbers are possible if repetition is not allowed.
case02: Repetition is allowed 
for hundreds place 4 numbers can accommodate , for tens place 5 numbers can accommodate and for ones place once again 5 numbers can accommodate. (here in hundreds place we can't use 0 so we have 4 numbers in all other each of the number is used)
so total ways when repetition us allowed is 4x5x5=100.

Let's look at your second question 
Let's assume that you first arranged English 4 book 
ways to arrange them is 4! = 24

then you put science 3 books
ways to arrange it would be 3!=6

then you put calculus 5 books
ways to arrange it would be 5!=120

Now you have three groups science calculus and English hence ways to arrange these three groups is 3!=6.
total ways =120x6x24x6=103680.

Comment: do you mean 120x6x144? Because you're multiplying 144 by 3! to factor in for the permutations of the objects? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake it was not 244 but it was 24

Comment: No problem! Where does the 3! factor in then?

Comment: suppose you have 3 distinct things then in how many ways you can arrange it !

Comment: Here u r having 3 group of books so

Comment: I know what you mean but you didn't put it in your final calculation. So I was confused. Shouldn't it be 4! x 3! x 5! x 3!

Comment: Then sorry again it's my mistake I am editing it now

Comment: Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We can divide into $2$ cases, Case $1$, where the first (leftmost) digit is even, and Case $2$, where the first digit is odd.

**Case 1:** There are $2$ possibilities for the first digit, since $0$ is forbidden.  For each of these, there are $2$ possibilities for the last digit, since it must be even.  And now there are $3$ digits left, any one of which can be used for the middle digit, giving $(2)(2)(3)$ numbers.

**Case 2:** There are $2$ choices for the first digit. For each of these, there are $3$ choices for the last digit, and then $3$ for the middle digit, giving  $(2)(3)(3)$ numbers.

Add.

Comment: But by your method answer coming is wrong

Comment: If there is a mistake (always possible!) one can point to *where* the mistake was made.

Comment: Would you check whether my answer given is correct or not ! please

Comment: I believe that the answer is $30$, not $48$.

Comment: Can u first explain what is wrong in my answer

Comment: The problem asks us for the number of **even** numbers that one can form. You counted **all** numbers. You took care of the condition that the first digit cannot be $0$, but not of the condition that the last digit must be $0$, $4$, or $6$.

Comment: Just to help with clarification numbers cannot be repeated. Also can you explain a little more why there are only 2 possibilities for the leftmost digit? Thanks!

Comment: I broke down into two **cases** (there are $4$ possibilities). The reason it is useful to do this is that if we use up an even digit for the leftmost digit, then we have a different number of choices for the last digit than if we use an odd number for the first digit.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank You

Comment: You are welcome. Your count would be correct if we wanted **all* numbers. But we only want the even numbers, and an even number must end in an even digit.

Answer (score 0):

**On case 1:**

First we will calculate how many numbers there are if the condition that the number is even is left out. For the first digit there are $4$ choices, for the second there are $4$ choices and for the third there are $3$ choices. So this results in $4\times 4\times 3=48$ possibilities.

If such a number is odd then it ends on $5$ or $7$.

How many numbers of the $48$ numbers end on $5$? Now for the first digit there are $3$ choices, for the second there are $3$ choices, showing that $3\times 3=9$ end on a $5$. Likewise we find that $9$ end on a $7$ and subtraction gives $48-9-9=30$ numbers that are even.